# What happens when mapping <s-c>?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I have two mappings like this:

```
nnoremap <s-c> zz
inoremap <s-c> <esc>zza
```

As you can see, I just want to use `<s-c>` to redraw the current line to the middle of the windows in both normal and insert mode. But, surprisingly, after that mapping, I cannot enter the uppercase `C` in insert mode any more. Why?

Is it because that the uppercase `C` by default mapped (recursively) to the `<s-c>`? (I guess this because in many keyboard pressing `<s-c>`has the same effect as pressing a uppercase C, that is, you get a `C` in your buffer.)

If so, how can I unmap it?

Comment: Because mapping `<s-c>` in insert mode means `Shift-c` or an uppercase letter c.  Thus, you cannot type an uppercase letter c in insert mode.

Answer (score 4):

By mapping a character in insert mode (or any mode) you overwrite the default behaviour. In your case, mapping `nnoremap <s-c> <esc>zza` overwrites the default behaviour of inserting a capital C.

The *noremap commands (e.g. nnoremap,inoremap,etc) do not use recursive mapping, i.e. all keys in the mapping act as though they have the default behaviour. If you would like to insert a capital C as well as using the previously mentioned mapping simply by adding it to the mapping. `nnoremap <s-c> C<esc>zza` should work.

Finally, no, you can't unmap the default behaviour for keys, only override it with other actions (including doing nothing, with `<nop>`).